# Firebase won't add local IP to authorized domains

Tags: firebase

I have my local dev server set up on its own IP (rather than using localhost), but when I try to add it to Firebase settings for authorized domains, it doesn't stick. I've also tried other regular-looking domains and they won't stick either. Is this section broken right now?

Comment: Firebase support is a more appropriate channel for this type of question - check out support@firebase.com.

Comment: I figged it out. You HAVE to hit space after entering a domain (even though you get the "successful save" alert without doing that)